# Touch specific coordinate (UI tests)

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

How can I touch specific coordinate with UITests?

When I'm recording tap on specific place, I have something like:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[[[[[[[[[[app.otherElements containingType:XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar 
identifier:@"Navigation Bar title"] 
childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element 
childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element 
childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element 
childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther] elementBoundByIndex:0] 
childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther].element 
childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeOther] 
elementBoundByIndex:0].staticTexts[@"Action"] tap];
```

Comment: You'd better break this in lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only tap specific coordinate referenced off of a known element. Meaning, you can't tap the pixel at coordinates (20, 400). Instead, you need to find an element and then tap something with an offset.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *label = app.labels[@"Label Name"];
XCUICoordinate *coordinate = [label coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.5, 1.2));
[coordinate tap];
```

I documented more information on how to figure out the right offset in my [UI Testing Cheat Sheet](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-quot-pull-to-refresh-quot) post.

---

If you are just trying to tap the `Action` button you can access it directly (instead of drilling down with all of those queries).

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[[[app.navigationBars element].staticTexts[@"Action"] tap];
```

Comment: Today I got to know what is normalized offset. Suppose you found a button XYZ, then in XYZ.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx, dy), dx,dy = 0,0 will be its top-left corner. dx,dy = 1,1 will be its bottom-right corner. dx,dy = 0.5,0.5 will be its middle

Comment: You can use any value for dx,dy beyond 0 and 1. Just point is that 1dx  measures width of current element you are referencing from, and 1dy is equal to height of the current element you are referencing from. 

So if you have three buttons of equal size placed horizontally next to each other, then leftMostButton.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 1.5, dy: 0.5)).tap() will tap the center of the middle button, and dx,dy = 2.5,0.5 will tap the center of the right most button

Answer (score 2):

To tap specific co-ordinates of the screen, build an `XCUICoordinate` from a window element.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *window = [app.windows elementAtIndex:0];
// Get co-ordinate for the top left corner of the screen
XCUICoordinate *origin = [window coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)];
// Get coordinate relative to the top left of the screen
XCUICoordinate *myCoordinate = [origin coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(40.0, 100.0)];

[coordinate tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is swift version

```
let point = app.labels["labelName"].coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy:0))
point.tap()
```